# Migrating from PHP 7.1.x to PHP 7.2.x json_decode() change

Tags: php, migration, php-7.2, jsondecoder

[The official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.json_decode-changes) says:

> The json_decode() function option, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY, is now used
>   if the second parameter (assoc) is NULL. Previously,
>   JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY was always ignored.

This code (AFAIK) accomplishes this change and condition :

```
<?php

$an_object = new StdClass();
$an_object->some_atrribute = "value 1";
$an_object->other_atrribute = "value 2";

//an object
print_r($an_object);

$encoded = json_encode($an_object);

//here (null is passed in the second parameter)
$output = json_decode($encoded,null,512);

//using 7.2 should be array, however it is an object
print_r($output);

//array
$output = json_decode($encoded,true);
print_r($output);
```

However only the last print, prints as array.

Am I understanding something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [function signature](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = FALSE 
  [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

> **options**
>
> Bitmask of JSON decode options. Currently there are two
>   supported options. The first is `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` that allows
>   casting big integers to string instead of floats which is the default.
>   The second option is `JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY` that has **the same effect as
>   setting `assoc` to `TRUE`**.

It means you can set the *fourth* parameter to `JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY` even if you didn't set the *second* parameter to `true` for some reason, but set it to `null` instead. But default value of this fourth param is 0, which means no transformation (from object to array) if only second param is set to `null`.

Here's [the shortened demo](https://3v4l.org/b1mA6) showing the difference:

```
$an_object = new StdClass();
$an_object->attr = 'value';

$encoded = json_encode($an_object);
print_r( json_decode($encoded, true, 512, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY)  );
print_r( json_decode($encoded, false, 512, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY) );
print_r( json_decode($encoded, null, 512, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY)  );
```

Here you'll see array and object printed as result of first and second decode ops in all the PHP versions. But the third op will result in array only since PHP 7.2.0.

Comment: Nice thanks.  "JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY, is now used if the second parameter (assoc) is NULL".however is not a nice writing. Could be better.

Comment: yea the worst way to describe it written on the official guide!!

Comment: and who would pass `null` for a "bool $assoc = FALSE"?? Its a bool field